# About Eigenvalues

Tags: calculus, matrices, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

We are given $\frac{dN}{dT}=2N(N-10)(1-\frac{N}{100}) - N(t)$ is population size at any given time $t$. We can find the equilibria by putting the rate of change of $N'(t)=0$. Now the question asked is - use the eigenvalue approach to determine the stability of the equilibria you found.

Need help in understanding, how $N''(t)$ will lead to the answer. I am not very clear about "Eigenvalues" either.

Being my first question, it may be trivial, but I am here to learn.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{dN}{dt} = f(N) $

The equilibria are the roots of $f(N) = 0$.  An equilibrium will be stable if $f(N-\epsilon)$ is positive, **and** $f(N+\epsilon)$ is negative, where $\epsilon $ is a small positive scalar.  Now using Taylor series expansion of $f(N-\epsilon)$, it is given by,

$f(N - \epsilon) = f(N) - f'(N) \epsilon = - f'(N) \epsilon $

and

$ f(N + \epsilon ) = f'(N) \epsilon $

Hence, an equilibrium will be stable iff $f'(N) $ is negative.

Now $f(N) = 2 N(N-10)(1 - \dfrac{N}{100}) $

So the critical points are $N = 0, N= 10, N = 100$

$f'(N) = 2 (N - 10)(1 - \dfrac{N}{100}) + 2 N (1 - \dfrac{N}{100}) - \dfrac{1}{50} N (N - 10) $

Hence, $f'(0) = 2 (-10) = -20 , f'(10) = 20 (1 - 0.1) = 18, f'(100) = -2(90) = -180$

Therefore, the stable equilibria are $N = 0$, and $N = 100$.